# php - Mysql with <b> tag in database is making text bold when displaying in website

Tags: php

One of the contents in my database has `<b>Test</b>`.

My problem is when I display with php it displays `<b>test</b>` How do I make it output `<b>Test</b>`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you:

```
echo '<pre>';
echo htmlspecialchars($YOUR_HTML);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score -1):

using htmlspecialchars you can display all the  **and**  tags without them having an effect, $content is what is read from the database before it is output...

```
$content = htmlspecialchars($content);
```

Comment: Op does not want to remove the html

Comment: OP previously asked how to not show the bold text, has now updated the question, so yes thank you I've updated my answer